# Chain rule, partial derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

$z =  x^{2} \sin(y), x = 3s^{2} +3t^{2}, y = −2st$
$$$$
Use the chain rule to find $\frac {\partial z}{\partial s}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$ as functions of $x, y, s$ and $t$.
And find numerical values of $\frac {\partial z}{\partial s}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$ when $(s,t) = (−4,−5).$
$$$$
I got: $\;\frac {\partial z}{\partial s}  = 2x\sin(y)(9s^{2}) + x^{2}\cos(y)(-2t)$ .$$$$
To $\;\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = 2x\sin(y)(6t) + x^{2}\cos(y)(-2s) $ $$$$
And: $\frac {\partial z}{\partial s}(-4,-5) = -9504\sin(40) + 10890\cos(40) $.
$$$$ To $\;\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} (-4,-5) = 1980\sin(40)+8712\cos(40)$
$$$$
My classmate said he was wrong, but he didn't explain where. Any explanation will be of great help.

Comment: That $(9s^2)$ seems to be wrong.

Comment: It was supposed to be **6s**, right?

Comment: That's right, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much